# Are Dr. Allen and Obed Marsh the same person?

Tags: the-lovecraft-investigations

Spoilers ahead.

In [*The Lovecraft Investigations*](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p06spb8w), are Dr. Allen and Obed Marsh two names for the same person?

In episode 10 of "[The Case of Charles Dexter Ward](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p06spcbl)", Kennedy Fisher says this about her time in Iraq:

> We tracked down Melody Cartwright. She's here with Barbara Sayers and some other guy who's all covered in bandages.

In episode 5 of "[The Whisperer In Darkness](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/m000lhkv)", Parker makes it clear who that bandaged person really is:

> You were with Dr. Allen and Barbara Sayers and Ezra Weeden. Allen's face was covered in bandages.

So far, everything makes sense, but in episode 5 of "[The Shadow Over Innsmouth](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p08y46bf)" Albert Wilmarth alias John Silence says this:

> Melody Cartwright was abducted by Barbara Sayers and Obed Marsh with the intention of shifting the Ipku-Aya personality into her body.

**Does this entail that Obed Marsh went under the name of Dr. Allen?**

Assuming that I didn't miss anything, Dr. Allen didn't occur in "The Shadow Over Innsmouth." The voice actors of the two characters are different though:

- Dr. Allen: Adam Godley
- Obed Marsh: Kyle Soller

The change in voice *might* be explained away with the head injuries Dr. Allen sustained.

On the other hand, Albert Wilmarth's statement might mean that Obed Marsh took place in the kidnapping of Melody Cartwright but didn't go with her to Iraq afterwards. But it would make sense if Obed Marsh would be present at the Ipku-Aya ritual.

An argument for them being two separate individuals is this statement from Eleanor Peck about the Melusine ritual in episode 6 of "The Shadow Over Innsmouth:"

> That ritual was Marsh, Lansdale, and Tillinghast trying again to bring Azathoth through. [...] After Melusine, Edward Lansdale is killed in battle and Ipku-Aya passes from Edward Lansdale to Rudolf von Sebottendorf.

Given that Ipku-Aya later passes from von Sebottendorf to Dr. Allen, this would indicate that Dr. Allen and Marsh are two different individuals.

Comment: I've twitted at the podcast's writer. Hopefully we'll get a response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dr. Allen and Obed Marsh are two different individuals. If you listen to the last two episodes of *The Shadow Over Innsmouth*, you will hear:

> Casey, the hotel receptionist, is revealed as Obed Marsh. Dr Allen was masquerading as the Librarian in the first season, so Kennedy would have recognised him sooner if they were the same.

Although she recognises the Allen family member growing the mushrooms in the crypt.

Comment: Thanks, that's very plausible. Still, this one statement by Albert Wilmarth puzzles me: "Melody Cartwright was abducted by Barbara Sayers and **Obed Marsh** ..."